# How to pass a <ui:inputdate> value from a clientside controller of a lightning component to a serverside controller's @Auraenabled method?

Tags: lightning-aura-components

My purchaseOrderSearchComponent.cmp

```
<aura:component controller="purchaseOrderSearchControllerRe" implements="force:appHostable,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId,forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes" access="global">
<aura:attribute name="date" type="Date" access="GLOBAL"/>
<aura:handler name="change" value="{!v.date}" action="{!c.dateChange}"/>

<div class="slds-form-element">
           <div class="slds-form-element__control">
             <ui:inputDate aura:id="orderDate" label="Order Date"
                               class="slds-input"
                               labelClass="slds-form-element__label"
                               change="{!c.dateChange}" 
                               value="{!v.date}"
                               displayDatePicker="true"/>
 </div>
 </div>
<div class="slds-form-element">

            <ui:button label="Submit" 
                       class="slds-button slds-button--neutral"
                       labelClass="label"
                       press="{!c.searchPO}"/>
 </div>
```

My purchaseOrderSearchComponentcontroller.js

```
 ({
searchPO: function(component, event, helper){
         helper.getPurchaseOrderList(component);

    //Set up the callback

  },
dateChange: function(component, event, helper){
               console.warn("dateChange");
               var date = component.get("v.date");
               console.warn("date is: ", date);
             }
)}
```

My purchaseOrderSearchComponentHelper.js

```
    ({
    getPurchaseOrderList: function(component) {

        var ordrdate = component.get("v.date");

        console.log('ordrdate='+ordrdate);
        var action = component.get("c.getSearchList");

        action.setParams({  "ordrdate" : ordrdate });
    //Set up the callback
    var self = this;
    action.setCallback(this, function(actionResult) {
     //do stuffs; 
    });
    $A.enqueueAction(action);
  }
})
```

My purchaseOrderSearchControllerRe apex class

```
    @AuraEnabled
  public static List<Purchase_Order__c> getSearchList(Date ordrdate) {

    System.debug('ordrdate='+ordrdate);
}
```

I am getting **ordrdate=null** in debug startement. But in console.log statement I am getting a date value.
What wrong am i doing? I have tried a lot to figure out...But all in vain.
Any help!!!

Comment: In the console log, are you getting the correct date in both logs?

Comment: Yes. I am getting the correct date.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all your controller is not closed properly.
The actual method is

```
({
    //..............
})
```

Modify the dateChange methods as below.

```
dateChange: function(component, event, helper){
        var dateField = component.find("orderDate");
        var date = dateField.get("v.value");
        component.set("v.date", date);
}
```

Lastly, change the parameter type from Date to String in apex.
It can be converted to date using

```
Date.valueOf(ordrdate);
```

Comment: dateChange: function(component, event, helper){
                       var dateField = component.find("orderDate");
                       var date = dateField.get("v.value");
                       component.set("v.date", date);
}
worked for me with a little change  _component.set("v.date", date)_ instead of _ component.get("v.date", date);_ . I think that's a typo you made. 
It is working. A great help. Thanks a lot  @JunaidPKhader

Comment: That means it is not possible to pass a an argument of type Date to a @Auraenabled method. Am i right??

Comment: Yes you are right.