# Capture the value ui:inputDate on change

Tags: lightning-aura-components

How can i capture value changed for ui:inputDate and pass to server side controller. i have tried multiple ways but anything is not working

first controller function

```
componentValueChange : function(component,event){

var componentId =event.getSource().getLocalId(); // getting aura id value
var componentValue =component.find(componentId).get("v.value");// undefined...working for other input components
}
```

I have tried other way

```
https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F0000000BJYcIAO
```

after capturing value from attribute and called server side function it went in infinite loop what i observed from above solution is at component initialize time it calling and once value change going into recursive.

please let me know if you have any solution to capturing the date value and store database record.

Answer (score 4):

I tried the change event on the `ui:inputdate`, and the controller action does not seem to fire on change. Instead try creating a change handler that calls the defined action from controller

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/js_cb_data_change.htm

**component:**

```
<aura:component >
        <aura:attribute name="date" type="Date" access="GLOBAL"/>
        <aura:handler name="change" value="{!v.date}" action="{!c.changedate}"/> 
        <ui:inputDate  aura:id="dateValue" value="{!v.date}" label="date" displayDatePicker="true"/>
</aura:component>
```

**controller:**

```
({
    changedate : function(component, event, helper) {
         var date_val = component.get("v.date");
        alert("changed date:"+ date_val);
    }
})
```

**Update:**

There is something off about the date, I assume it is the format in which the date is being passed. From official docs the basic data types should be supported. I tried integer and it passed fine to the apex controller.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/ref_attr_types_basic.htm

I tried adjusting the format to YYYY-MM-DD still no luck I get null values when I pass this as date to the apex controller(*default format for dates in apex)

From this post :[How to pass a <ui:inputdate> value from a clientside controller of a lightning component to a serverside controller's @Auraenabled method?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/133082/how-to-pass-a-uiinputdate-value-from-a-clientside-controller-of-a-lightning-c)

I see that you can pass the date as string and convert it back into a date in your apex controller. I was able to pass the date as string with no issues.

**component:**

```
<aura:component controller="datevalcontroller">
        <aura:attribute name="date_vals" type="Date" access="GLOBAL"/>
    <aura:attribute name="total" type="Integer" default="360"/>

    <aura:handler name="change" value="{!v.date_vals}" action="{!c.changedate}"/> 
    <ui:inputDate aura:id="dateValue" value="{!v.date_vals}" label="date" displayDatePicker="true" format="YYYY-MM-DD"/>
</aura:component>
```

**controller:**

```
({
    changedate : function(cmp, event, helper) {
        var date_val = cmp.get("v.date_vals");
alert(date_val);

        var action = cmp.get("c.passdateval");
        action.setParams({date_value : date_val});
        action.setCallback(this, function(response) {
            var state = response.getState();
            if (state === "SUCCESS") {
                alert("From server: " + response.getReturnValue());
            }
            else if (state === "ERROR") {
                var errors = response.getError();
                if (errors) {
                    if (errors[0] && errors[0].message) {
                        console.log("Error message: " + 
                                 errors[0].message);
                    }
                } else {
                    console.log("Unknown error");
                }
            }
        }); 
        $A.enqueueAction(action);
    }
})
```

**apex controller:**

```
public class datevalcontroller {
    @AuraEnabled
    public static String passdateval(String date_value){
        system.debug('### Date val: '+ date_value);
        return date_value;
    }
}
```

Comment: It kind of looks like overkill, but this is a pretty nifty example of aura:handler.

Comment: The ui:inputDate doc seem to support change evebt, not sure why the event is not firing the controller action on change

Comment: @Rao, it is working fine for me,pass this value to server side you will get infinite loop. as i mentioned in question also that i used this solution but not working for server side call.

Comment: Can you paste the code on how you pass the date variable over to the server controller

Comment: have you observed this {!c.changedate} calling twice one is at the time of component initialize and other when value changed

Comment: there is something off about the date datatype, I have been trying with integer, string the param seem to pass from controller to server fine. With Date I get null values, looking around the only way to handle is to pass it as a string and convert to date format in the controller.

Comment: @Rao how did you convert? Date.valuof or date.parse doesn't work for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Advice: **do not use ui: stuff** and build your own ones, like inputDate for example, it's longer but you'll have much more flexibility  :)

Simplified version ( not containing label management ):

Cmp:

```
<aura:component access="global">
    <aura:attribute name="value" type="Date" access="global" description="Input/Output date value"/>
    <input aura:id="irm-input-field"
           type="date" 
           onblur="{!c.doSetValue}"
           value="{!v.value}" />
</aura:component>
```

JS:

```
    doSetValue : function(component, event) {
        var InputFieldMiniCmp = component.find('irm-input-field');
        var Val = InputFieldMiniCmp.getElement().value;
        component.set('v.value',Val);
    }
```

Call from your component :

```
<aura:component controller="datevalcontroller">
        <aura:attribute name="date_vals" type="Date" access="GLOBAL"/>
    <aura:attribute name="total" type="Integer" default="360"/>

    <aura:handler name="change" value="{!v.date_vals}" action="{!c.changedate}"/> 
    <c:inputDate aura:id="dateValue" value="{!v.date_vals}" label="date" />
</aura:component>
```

Comment: thank you Nicolas, i will try this. but if i more than one date types in components, it causes  lot of additional code.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try **updateOn="blur"** , it's supposed to update the value only when the user leaves the ui:component

```
<aura:component controller="datevalcontroller">
        <aura:attribute name="date_vals" type="Date" access="GLOBAL"/>
    <aura:attribute name="total" type="Integer" default="360"/>

    <aura:handler name="change" value="{!v.date_vals}" action="{!c.changedate}"/> 
    <ui:inputDate aura:id="dateValue" value="{!v.date_vals}" label="date" displayDatePicker="true" format="YYYY-MM-DD" updateOn="blur"/>
</aura:component>
```

Described here: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/aura_compref_ui_inputDate.htm