# ui:inputDate change month event

Tags: lightning-aura-components, inputdate

I have a question can I add event in standard ui:inputDate lightning component on changin month in date picker?
[image]

Comment: Have you tried adding *change="{!c.dateChange}"* and handling the event in controller?

Comment: Check this link. https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/146790/capture-the-value-uiinputdate-on-change